# Separate view and controller action for changing User passwords in rails 3r

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model, and authentication is provided by has_secure_password. I would like to implement a separate view for password edits.

Are there any decent tutorials or learning resources where I can go for more on how to best accomplish this?

My simplified model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, format: { with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i }
  validates :password, :length => { :within => 6..40 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true    
end
```

I'd like to make sure that the password validations only run when the user is editing the change_password page, and that there is a separate page for editing passwords.

I imagine I need new controller actions, like `edit_password` and `update_password`. Would I then do: `validates :password, on: [:create, :update_password]`?

I'm a bit stuck and would really like to browse some sample code or blog posts on this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run validations only when

```
1.creating the new user
2.updating the password
```

You can go for [conditional validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :update_password

  validates :password, :length => { :within => 6..40 }, :if => new_record? || update_password
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, :if => new_record? || update_password
end
```

And in your controller you need to set the update_password is true.

```
class PasswordsController < ActionController::Base

 def edit
   #You will render the password edit view here
 end

 def update
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @user.update_password = true
   @user.password = params[:password]
   @user.password_confirmation = params[:password_confirmation]
   if @user.save
      #success redirect here
   else
      render :edit
   end
 end

end
```

FYI.

```
validates :password, on: [:create, :update_password]
```

Here :create, :update_password does not means the controller actions.It means the various states of the user object. Its includes :create, :update and update_password is not valid state.

Comment: thanks, I ended up ditching the idea of a separate page for password edits, and took your advice to run validations like this:   `validates :password, :length => { :within => 6..40 }, allow_blank: { on: :update }` and `validates :password_confirmation, presence: { :if => :password_digest_changed? }`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to learn how to do it is to look through devise source code (or any other auth gems), for example, password controller
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb

Comment: thanks, I had a look at it, and decided to do things a different way as it's not a critical feature.